# Order django-tables2 by name instead of FK

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a django-table2 where each row contains a foreign-key to a User object.  When I click on the sort arrow for the User name it sorts by (I presume) the key of the User instead of the name.  I can't find anything in the docs on how to fix this.

Python 2.7, Django 1.5.1, django-tables2 0.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swear I looked through the docs repeatedly.  Not sure how I missed this.

http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#specifying-alternative-ordering-for-a-column

`Owner = tables.Column(order_by=("Owner.Full_Name"))`